# WebElement object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Why is this appening?

This works

```
time_elements = li_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("time")

message_elements = li_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "span.message")

message_element = message_elements[len(time_elements)-1]
```

but when I change to:

```
time_elements = li_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "time")

message_elements = li_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "span.message")

message_element = message_elements[len(time_elements)-1] 
#i need this in order to get the last entry
```

it doesn't. I know I'm not giving much but I believe I'm missing something simple.

already tried

```
time_elements = li_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "time")
```

Error:

```
message_element = message_elements[len(time_elements)-1]
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: seems like you're treating a single webelement reference as if it were an array.  find_element returns a single webelement reference... find_elements returns an array of webelement references.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `message_elements` is not a list.
You are trying to get some object (element) from that list by an index `len(time_elements)-1` by

```py
message_elements[len(time_elements)-1]
```

while `message_elements` is not a list, it is a **single** web element object.

Comment: yes but like i said above iv already tried time_elements = li_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "time") and nothing, am i missing something?

Comment: thanks, thats the issue, i dont know how to get the list. like this li_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("time") it works but i get message that it will be deprecated

Answer (score 0):

See this line

```
li_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("time")
```

`li_element` must be a web element and on top of that, you are using `find_elements` which will return **a list of web elements** if found, if not then the size of the list will be zero.

The list name, in this case, is `time_elements`

When you are writing this line:

```
message_element = message_elements[len(time_elements)-1]
```

this means that `message_elements` is a list and you are looking for the length of `time_elements`.

Since `message_elements` in both the cases aren't really a list and it is a single web element, you are facing the exception.

You cannot have an index on a single web element type, it has to be a list of web elements.